# Can this damage to Quartzite corners be repaired?

Tags: stone, kitchen-island

Install was today and it appears the slab was dropped as two corners on one end had their corners snap off. The stone guys clearly tried to repair it... and have more days of work to do. Can it be fixed?

[More photos](https://imgur.com/gallery/4HN01im)

[image]

Comment: Brutal.  Double book end with waterfall - that's a pricey counter top.  What does your fine print say about slab failures?  Typically you'd have to pay for new slab but the installer would maybe eat the cost of labor - are you ready to pay for ( I assume two new slabs? )  Given the install I'd be paying for new slabs or finding a new stone guy.  You'll get more traction if you put the photos into your post.

Comment: Did your professional installer do that? I would insist on a new install or a hefty discount

Comment: If they can polish that to be perfectly flat, then personally, I’d accept it. But you are paying for new and perfect, so it’s your call.

Comment: @matt yes it was a pro installation, whatever sub my general contractor uses of course.

Comment: It's going to come down to who has the best lawyer & insurance. Reject it. You didn't order a broken slab, badly repaired. If you accept it you'll see the repair every single time you walk in the kitchen.

Comment: Whether you should fix it or confront your installer is off topic here as a matter of opinion. If you're asking whether and how it can be repaired, that's ok. Please see the [help].

Answer (score 0):

If the stone installer is a sub from your general contractor, he should be the one to confront the installer. You need to confront the GC and let them know of your dissatisfaction.

Like all the comments before, you are paying for a NEW product, not one that has already been put through the wringer.

Now in my opinion, I have seen a number of slab installs, and I have never seen one as sloppily done as this one. The joints at the corners are terrible. They need to blend in seamlessly. A pro installer should have no issue with doing so. With what you are left with as a so called finished product, tells me these guys either don't care about their work, or do not have enough experience to do it properly. That includes the handling of the stone to keep it from cracking to begin with.

By the way, you pay for it once, no exceptions. It is up to the GC to provide you with the product, he just so happens to use another company to do so.

Answer (score 0):

GCs typically are always in the power position as you've already paid for the portion of work that is currently being done.  They can walk and you'd have to sue to get your money back, find a new gc and accepted a timeline that goes to hell.  So it really depends on the GC relationship with the stone guy, the gc need to have happy clients and if he has leverage with the stone guy.

One solution is to cut the island 1" shorter which could work depending on the cabinetry and allow the stone guy just to recut at least the top piece which would only cost them labor.

I'd get the stone replaced or cut an 1" shorter.  That kind of defect is just too big.

The join isn't the best in the stone but not the worst I've seen either.  Probably fairly average for a quartzite.  You can certainly get better just depends on the price point of the job.

I've got a quartzite island being cut at the moment.  I am serving as the GC though.  My stone guy identified the weaknesses in the stone that run perpendicular to the vein in the stone I picked.  The island is being cut to minimize those weak areas but slabs can break on install and I'd be paying for a new slab if the current one breaks on install - unless like yours I can argue it was from incompetence.

Good luck !